# Angular interceptors and CORS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, http-headers, interceptor

I am trying to write an interceptor to add a token to all HTTP requests using Angular. I am using roughly the recipe given here - https://thinkster.io/interceptors

So the code uses http module factory and a `tokenInterceptor()` function. I can successfully add a token as a header to the request - but now when it passes through the interceptor, it gets blocked by some kind of CORS blocking mechanism. I get this error in chrome console -

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:/.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:/' is
>   therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I tried setting the access control allow origin header like below in my interceptor to no avail:

```
config.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
```

I have tried some suggestions online but none helped. Does anything at all need to be done on client side to fix CORS related issues - or is it all a server side concern?

Answer (score 6):

The server that’s responding to the request needs to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header for `OPTIONS` requests, not just for `GET` and `POST` requests.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

The reason the browser gives you that error is: before it attempts the actual request you’re trying to make from your frontend JS code, the browser sends an `OPTIONS` request to see if the server responds in a way indicating it’s opting in to receiving requests of the kind you’re trying to make.

So your server-side code needs to add handling for the `OPTIONS` request to respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` & `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`.

> Does anything at all need to be done on client side to fix CORS related issues - or is it all a server side concern?

There’s nothing you can do on the client side to change the behavior or to get your browser to not emit that error. CORS config is all a server-side concern. Your server must handle the `OPTIONS`.

> The response had HTTP status code 403.

That indicates an authorization failure. That could be just because your server isn’t configured to ever send a success response (`200` or `204`) for `OPTIONS` requests—in which case you must configure to to do that (to send a `200` or `204` with the right `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers and no response body)—or it could be because you’re trying to send a request that requires authorization and the authorization is failing.

Comment: This is actualy not true. I have similar problem, when I access the backend from angular, I get response, but when I add the interceptor and add some header, it responds with CORS error.

Answer (score 2):

> The same-origin policy is a critical security mechanism that restricts how a document or script loaded from one origin can interact with a resource from another origin. It helps isolate potentially malicious documents, reducing possible attack vectors.

This makes your app more secure.

> CORS gives web servers the ability to say they want to opt into allowing cross-origin access to their resources.

Instead of using CORS, I recommend you use a proxy in your angular server, so:

- in the browser, the real resource wont be displayed (more privacy and security)
- your code is more isolated from the specific source

### Implementation

Create a **proxy.conf.json** in your app

```
{

    "/client-api/*": {
      "target": "http://127.0.0.1",
      "pathRewrite": { "^/client-api": "" },
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
```

In your **angular.json** file, under `projects.<your-project-name>.architect.serve.options` add

```
"proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
```

Where you make the http request, just use the url origin `client-api`.

For example, to get the list of countries, you request `client-api/countries`, and the proxy will transform it to `http://127.0.0.1/countries`

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue: **receiving CORS error only when adding a token header with an interceptor:**

```js
req = req.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    "x-auth-token": session ? session.token : ''
  }
});
```

In my Node.js api server I had the following middleware:

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
  });
```

The problem were occurring because the 'x-auth-token' header was not in the list of allowed headers, so I added it:

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, x-auth-token'); // HERE
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
  });
```

This solved the problem instantly.