# Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status. 403 in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rest, cors, angular6, preflight

I am trying to make a PUT request but I get the following error:

```
Failed to load <localhost:8080/uaa/groups/dfsfaes8323df32>: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Apparently it works when I make GET and POST requests and works in postman but it doesn't work with the PUT request within my code.

Here is my request:

```
let link = "https://ice.<mydomain>.com/uaadev/Groups/{groupId}";
link = link.replace("{groupId}", data);
const updLoad = {
  displayName: this.groupInfoObjects.displayName,
  description: this.groupInfoObjects.description,
  zoneId : "uaa",
  schemas: [
 "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"
  ]
};
let Header = new Headers({
  Authorization: `Bearer {token}`.replace("{token}", this.token),
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Accept: "application/json",
  "if-Match":"*"
});
let Option = new RequestOptions({ headers: Header });

this.http.put(link, updLoad, Option).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.status);
    if (res.status === 200) {
 this.fetchGroupInfo(this.dataservice.getDTO("GroupId"));
      swal(" Updated Successfully");
    }
  },
  error => {
    console.log("errroroorororororor");
    console.log("error object " +error);
  }
);
```

Comment: You need to configure the `https://ice.<mydomain>.com` server so that it allows PUT requests for the `/uaadev/Groups/{groupId}` endpoint. Right now, the 403 server response indicates the server is disallowing PUT requests for that /uaadev/Groups/{groupId}` endpoint. There’s nothing you can do in your frontend JavaScript to affect/change that.

Comment: tagging on to @sideshowbarker here - yeah, it's completely unrelated to Angular or front-end code. You gotta configure the CORS on the backend to include `PUT`  or `PATCH` in the `Acces-Control-Allow-Methods` header. You might be able to get by with an opaque `fetch`, but again, depends on your backend setup.

Comment: Opaque fetch is done by setting `{mode:'no-cors'}` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
the process for solving these process is listed below:

1.create a proxy.conf.json file 
2.set it up like this:copy and paste the below code
{
  "/dev/*": {
    "target": "https://google.com/",
    "secure": false
  },
  "changeOrigin": false,
  "logLevel": "debug"
}

3. add this to your package.json :
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config ../Activated/proxy.conf.json",
Note:Activated is the folder name that contains the angular code.
4.you place your url link:
let link = "dev/Groups/{groupId}" (just a sample)`enter code here`

5.npm start to restart you application.
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because you have to make sure your server is configured to send a 200 or 204 for the [OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it) request that is triggered by the browser before the PUT request.

See the first response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43902712/angular-interceptors-and-cors)

The reason you get this with PUT is because it triggers OPTIONS (an additional preflight request by the browser) to see more about what methods trigger this you can look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests). Basically, the browser is "pinging" the server before the PUT.

What's frustrating is that it seems like a frontend issue because a PUT request will work while testing (i.e. if you use postman) but not the browser.

So it's not a frontend issue and cannot be solved using Angular.